# Read buttons from joystick with pygame

Tags: psychopy

I'm new to PsychoPy and am testing a few tasks. As a response mechanism I use the buttons on a joystick (logitech G27). I import pygame, and can detect button presses in (the Sternberg example of) PsychoPy, so that's okay. However, after a visual.TextSim command the application hangs and can only be aborted via the windows taskmanager. This occurs only if I have used:
pygame.init() somewhere earlier in the program.

I use windows 7 Pro.

Does anyone know how to solve that ?

Comment: Could you post a minimal script that reproduces the problem? I.e. one that initiates a Window, a TextStim, calls pygame.int() etc. That would help us identify the problem. Also state which PsychoPy version you use.

Comment: These two threads may be of interest: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/psychopy-users/pzyQwRuSPJY and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/psychopy-users/5ZSO6nL1YR8/EEox505h5toJ. They don't explain the interference with the TextStim, though.